# Unable to add members to O365 group with Group.ReadWrite.All permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Unable to add members to the group with Group.ReadWrite.All permission.

I created a bearer token for graph having a scope of Group.ReadWrite.All & User.Read. I tried calling below graph API which adds a member to the group. The token is generated with a user principal having owner membership to the requested group.

But I am able to do other activity on the group, except adding/removing members.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/members/$ref
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}"
}
```

also tried with below body

```
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{userid}"
}
```

error received: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add or remove a group member (or owner), you currently need *both* `Group.ReadWrite.All` and `User.ReadBasic.All` (at minimum, though you could also do this with `User.Read.All`).

One way you can look at it is that you need permission to update the group *and* permission to read the object you're adding to the group.